# Busqueda con JPA - JAVA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Estoy trabajando con persistencia en java y tengo esta función con la que trato de encontrar un concierto en la base de datos segun su fecha y la idgrupo.

el código de la tabla de la base de datos es el siguiente

```
CREATE TABLE CONCIERTO (
    IDCONCIERTO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CIUDAD VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FECHA TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    TICKETS INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRECIO FLOAT NOT NULL,
    IDGRUPO INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (IDGRUPO) REFERENCES GRUPO(IDGRUPO) 
);
```

y la función es esta

```
public Concierto findByFechaAndGrupo(Timestamp fecha, int idgrupo) throws DAOException {
    try {
        TypedQuery<Concierto> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Concierto c WHERE c.fecha = :fecha AND c.idgrupo = :idgrupo", Concierto.class);
        System.out.println("------------LLego?99--------------");
        
        query.setParameter("FECHA", fecha);   
        query.setParameter("IDGRUPO", idgrupo);
        Concierto concierto = query.getSingleResult();
        return concierto;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DAOException("Error al buscar el concierto por fecha y grupo", e);
    }
}
```

el error que recibo es un NullPointerException y he comprobado que salta en la linea que se crea el TypedQuery

Esta es la clase concierto

```
package es.ubu.lsi.model.conciertos;






@Entity
@Table(name="CONCIERTO", schema="HR")
public class Concierto implements Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IDCONCIERTO")
    private int idConcierto;
    
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE")
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(name = "CIUDAD")
    private String ciudad;
    
    @Column(name = "FECHA")
    private Timestamp fecha;
    
    @Column(name = "TICKETS")
    private int tickets;
    
    @Column(name = "PRECIO")
    private Float precio;
    
    @Column(name = "IDGRUPO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int idgrupo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDGRUPO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Grupo grupo;
    
    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public int getIdconcierto() {
        return this.idConcierto;
    }
    public void setIdConcierto(int idConcierto){
        this.idConcierto = idConcierto;
    }
    
    public Integer getIdGrupo() {
        return this.idgrupo;
    }
    
    public void setIdGrupo(int idgrupo){
        this.idgrupo = idgrupo;
    }
    
    public float getPrecio() {
        return this.precio;
    }
    
    public void setPrecio(float precio){
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return this.fecha;
    }
    
    public void setFecha(Timestamp fecha){
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    
    public int getTickets() {
        return this.tickets;
    }
    
    public void setTickets(int tickets){
        this.tickets = tickets;
    }
    public String getCiudad() {
        return this.ciudad;
    }
    public void setCiudad(String ciudad){
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }
    
    public Concierto() {
    }
    
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "concierto", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private Set<Compra> compras = new HashSet<>();

    //private Set<Compra> compras = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Compra> getCompras() {
        return compras;
    }
    
    public Concierto(Timestamp fecha, int idgrupo) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.idgrupo = idgrupo;
    }
    
}
```

No consigo dar con el error, he intentado tambien hacer la funcion de otra manera pero tiene que ser en JPA.

Me valdria otra solucion siempre que devuelva el concierto y no use otro sistema de persistencia.

Comment: Intuyo que el error debe ser que el `entityManager` no está inicializado. Es decir, tiene como valor `null`. Si intentas hacer `debug` y pones un breakpoint en la línea que tira el null pointer, probablemente puedas ver cuál es el objeto con valor `null`. Si no es ese el caso, te pido que edites el post y muestres el mensaje de error que estás obteniendo para tener una mejor idea de donde podría venir el problema